# Run sudo command in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I wrote a shell script like this

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo mkdir /var/www/html/test
sudo cp ./index.html /var/www/html/test/index.html
echo "Hi" > /var/www/html/test/index.html
```

if I runt this with `sudo` it works well.

```
$ sudo ./script.sh
```

but I don't want to run with `sudo`. because `echo` doesn't need root privilege. In other hand if I run this without `sudo` like this:

```
$ ./script.sh
```

for the first command (`mkdir`) it asks me for root password and second command doesn't run and give me a permission denied error.

How can I handle this situation?

Comment: It works for me all the way up to the `echo`, as index.html inherited the permissions of the containing folder. Try using `cp -p` to preserve permissions when copying.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your setup, e.g. in ubuntu if I run sudo 2 times, the second time I don't have to give the password. So it is possible that the second sudo DID run, without asking for password again.

You can clarify, try this:

```
sudo echo a
sudo echo b
```

It is most likely, as Kip K commented, the error originates from the echo "Hi"... since the normal user has no permission to write /var/www/html/test/index.html .

Kinda overkill, but you can give constant feedback like this:

```
sudo bash -c 'echo mkdir; mkdir /var/www/html/test'
sudo bash -c 'echo cp; cp ./index.html /var/www/html/test/index.html'
```

Comment: I undestood and deleted my comment.

Answer (score 0):

Try `chown` for directory `test`:

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo bash -c 'mkdir /var/www/html/test && chown -R USER /var/www/html/test'
cp ./index.html /var/www/html/test/index.html
echo "Hi" > /var/www/html/test/index.html
```

or `... chmod o+w /var/www/html/test`